# Pass numerical id to JS function from html dropbox

Tags: javascript, html, codeigniter

Im developing codegniter web application first time. there i have used js function inside the html  tag everything there works fine. please find my code below .there i have a  alert dialog. Which  prints names of catogories (for an example aaaa,bbbb,cccc) but i want to retrieve index of that catogory ( for an example 1,2,3) .please help me.

**JS code**

```
<script type="text/javascript">

                   function activate_match()
                   {
                       var cat_id = $('select#cato').val();
                       alert(cat_id);

                   }

</script>
```

function call snippet

```
<select name="cat" id="cato" onchange="activate_match()">
<?php
                   foreach($catogories as $cat) {
                    echo'<option value="' . $cat . '">' . $cat . '</option>';

                }
                ?>

                </select>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can you this code

```
$("#cato").change(function() {
       alert(document.getElementById("cato").selectedIndex);
});
```

You can check jsfiddle here :

```
http://jsfiddle.net/naveenkumarpg/cbo2wrxk/
```

Answer (score 1):

at any user action you can check with value will give selected value 
it can be click or on change

```
$("#cato").val();
```

Comment: you can use this as well, i just gave example how to get value using javascript.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
$('select#cato:selected').index();
```

Comment: it prints -1 to all the selected values dude didnt work

Answer (score 0):

```
$("#cato").change(function() {
    alert($(this).val());
});
```

Answer (score 0):

This will work.

```
function activate_match(){
       alert($("#cato").val());
});
```